# How can i create StateClient object in LoginController using service url or microsoft app credentials?

Tags: c#, bots, skype, botframework

I am working on bot framework technology, in one of my project I want to create the state client object using service Url or Microsoft credentials in my LoginController.cs

This is the code I wrote in LoginController.cs, it's working in bot emulator but after published my bot and added it to skype then it's not working.

```
 //[HttpGet, Route("api/{userid}/authorize")]
    [HttpGet, Route("api/{userid}/token")]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> Authorize(string userid, string code)
    {
        AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token/");
        ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(Constants.Constants.ADClientId, Constants.Constants.ADClientSecret);
        AuthenticationResult ar = await ac.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(Constants.Constants.apiBasePath + userid + "/token"), cc, "https://api.office.com/discovery/");
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ar.AccessToken))
        {
           // var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("http://localhost:9000/"));
            // var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("http://skype.botframework.com/"));
            //var microsoftAppCredentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(appId: "ace15a7e-b7f6-4776-a6a3-a58c0314bd01", password: "X7BS9hJt0skSBu6z9kgW1FB");
            //var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("http://skype.botframework.com/"),microsoftAppCredentials,addJwtTokenRefresher:true);
            //var stateClient = new StateClient(microsoftAppCredentials);

            var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("https://apis.skype.com/"));
            //var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("https://api.slack.com/"));

            if (stateClient != null)
            {
                var userId = userid.Replace("-", ":");
                var getData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, userid);

                //var getData = await client.B.GetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, userid);
                getData.Data = ar.Serialize();
                getData.ETag = "*";
                var foo = await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, userid, getData);

                //var foo = await client.Bots.SetUserDataAsync(Constants.Constants.botId, userid, getData);
            }
            //return Request.CreateResponse(foo);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri("/loggedin.html", UriKind.Relative);
            return response;
        }
        else
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);

    }
```

Please tell how to resolve above problem.

-Pradeep

Comment: Wait, so what code do you use in real environment instead of the string "http://localhost:9000" ?

Comment: I used this one for creating state client object var stateClient = new StateClient(new Uri("https://apis.skype.com/"));

Comment: but when I am trying to set the accestoken into bot state at that time I got the exception as "Unable to deserialize the response". tell me how to solve it. see the above code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The url for the state client service is the following, independent of channel.

```
        this.BaseUri = new Uri("https://state.botframework.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the helper method to create your stateclient:

```
StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
```

Comment: I know by using activity reference we can create state client object but in  my scenario I want to create the state client object in my login controller not in message controller. when I click on this  var url = $"https://userpresencebot.azurewebsites.net/api/"+HttpUtility.UrlEncode(activity.From.Id)+"  url it will go to login controller then after click on sign-in button it will call above method what I was posted in my question.